# Get exchange rates for BCH

Tags: coinbase-api

When it's requested `v2/exchange-rates?currency=BCH`, it's received a list of rates of every currency, but in `EUR` shows `0.00`

Is this a normal behavior?

I guess this a bug because there's a exchange rate for `USD`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Guillermo sorry I missed that. Hopefully this GET I captured from the python client will help you. Still including the original fix to the python library in case it helps (also used to capture the GET)

```
GET /v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
CB-VERSION: 2016-02-18
CB-ACCESS-KEY: ###
CB-ACCESS-SIGN: ###
CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: <epoch>
```

---

The coinbase python client has an issue (jan-2018) ad requires a change to the params in:

> coinbase\wallet\client.py

from

```
response = self._get('v2', 'prices', 'spot', data=params)
```

to

```
response = self._get('v2', 'prices', 'spot', params=params)
```

Comment: I'm not using any library. I'm testing with a simple cURL, and it's not working